# OCAML set up in emacs - autocompletion on dot

Tags: emacs, ocaml

OSX 10.13.4 / Emacs 25.3 (9) / The OCaml toplevel, version 4.06.1.

New to OCAML and to Emacs and trying to understand how to have autocompletion on dot.
My init.el looks like this:

```
;;---------------------------------------
;; OCAML MODE CONFIGURATION
;; --------------------------------------
> (add-hook 'tuareg-mode-hook 'tuareg-imenu-set-imenu) (setq
> auto-mode-alist
>       (append '(("\\.ml[ily]?$" . tuareg-mode)
>                 ("\\.topml$" . tuareg-mode))
>               auto-mode-alist)) (autoload 'utop-setup-ocaml-buffer "utop" "Toplevel for OCaml" t) (add-hook 'tuareg-mode-hook
> 'utop-minor-mode) (add-hook 'tuareg-mode-hook 'merlin-mode) (setq
> merlin-use-auto-complete-mode t) (setq merlin-error-after-save nil)
```

For some reason completion on dot says: 
    apply: Searching for program: No such file or directory, /Users/xxxx/.opam/system/bin/ocamlmerlin

I am a bit lost with this OPAM...

`opam switch system` gives me:

```
# To setup the new switch in the current shell, you need to run:
eval `opam config env`
```

and `opam list` gives me:

```
 # Installed packages for system:
    base-bigarray        base  Bigarray library distributed with the OCaml compiler
    base-bytes           base  Bytes library distributed with the OCaml compiler
    base-threads         base  Threads library distributed with the OCaml compiler
    base-unix            base  Unix library distributed with the OCaml compiler
    conf-m4                 1  Virtual package relying on m4
    conf-which              1  Virtual package relying on which
    jbuilder       1.0+beta20  Fast, portable and opinionated build system
    ocamlfind           1.8.0  A library manager for OCaml
```

`Thanks to @Lhooq:  install merlin`  works!

```
# Installed packages for system:
base-bigarray        base  Bigarray library distributed with the OCaml compiler
base-bytes           base  Bytes library distributed with the OCaml compiler
base-threads         base  Threads library distributed with the OCaml compiler
base-unix            base  Unix library distributed with the OCaml compiler
biniou              1.2.0  Binary data format designed for speed, safety, ease o
conf-m4                 1  Virtual package relying on m4
conf-which              1  Virtual package relying on which
cppo                1.6.4  Equivalent of the C preprocessor for OCaml programs
easy-format         1.3.1  High-level and functional interface to the Format mod
jbuilder       1.0+beta20  Fast, portable and opinionated build system
merlin              3.0.5  Editor helper, provides completion, typing and source
ocamlfind           1.8.0  A library manager for OCaml
yojson              1.4.1  Yojson is an optimized parsing and printing library f
```

Comment: Could you type in `opam switch system` then `opam list`? It seems like you don't have merlin installed.

Comment: `opam install merlin` and try again.

Comment: Thanks - updated as an edit to my question.  Note: I am using the shell from emcas (C-!).  But terminal gives the same answers.

Comment: works now - updated edits for clarity.  Thank you

Now how do I get the nice show of possible completions?

Comment: It should be bound to `M-tab`. Other informations [here](https://github.com/ocaml/merlin/wiki/emacs-from-scratch)